# Is there a way to compare text files through Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, diff

I am trying to find a way to compare two text files through Flex and show that diff in the UI.
Is there a util or a way to do that?

Comment: Do you want to compare two text files in Flex?  Or compare two text files in Flash Builder?  They are two radically different questions.  I assume you mean Flash Builder, so I'm going to remove the Flex tag [and also add Flash Builder]

Comment: I want to compare two text files in Flex. Not Flash Builder. I'm working on a project where the user can select multiple files and do a diff between them.

Comment: It was the tags for eclipse-plugin or FlexBuilder that made me think you wanted to do the compare in Flash Builder; not in Flex; so I'm removing those tags, as they have no relation to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read local files with the FileReference object, so the answer is yes. Using this API you can load the files, but comparing them is not a feature that is built into the framework, so you will have to supply a mechanism to do that once the files are loaded.

More on loading local files can be found here: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/08/20/reading-and-writing-local-files-in-flash-player-10/.