# Compare text files in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Is there a utility or thirdparty library out there to compare two text files in flex. Assuming that, I have loaded two different text files using the 'FileReference', and now I want to compare the contents of these two. Similar to the SVN diff, I want to find out the edited/added/deleted content for each line.

I have gone through this thread [ [Is there a way to compare text files through Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871455/is-there-a-way-to-compare-text-files-through-flex) ] but it's not answered here.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not aware of any 3rd party libraries/classes that will do this for you, though I coded a "diff" viewer up for xml files for my own use to compare XML property files and pom.xml files that does node based comparison, so order doesn't matter just the name of the node and the value (used AS3/AIR).  Writing something similar up to give you results like diff shouldn't be too difficult, more on diff algos here http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DiffAlgorithm they have a link on that page to a Java implementation that looks like it could be ported but is GPL.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this link will guide you towards your solution. May have to do some tweaking to work with your feature list, but it should get you 90% of the way there.

[A diff/patch solution for Flash: a proof of concept Monte Carlo algorithm for comparing text versions in as3](http://blog.controul.com/2009/05/diff-patch-for-flash-as3/)

I just searched for 'as3 file differential' in Google.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link, I was using this http://blogs.adobe.com/charles/2011/12/diff-library-for-actionscript.html, but without semanthics it was pretty useless for me. http://blog.controul.com/2009/05/diff-patch-for-flash-as3/ was much better for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's no one, yet.

Given the similarities between as3 and js, a port from one of this two libraries should be straightfoward

http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/source/browse/trunk/javascript/diff_match_patch_uncompressed.js

http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/